# An iterative logarithmic transformation of a power series

Tags: limits, logarithms, power-series, closed-form, lambert-w

Consider the following iterative process. We start with the function having all $1$'s in its Taylor series expansion:
$$f_0(x)=\frac1{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+O\left(x^5\right).\tag1$$
Then, at each step we apply the following transformation:
$$f_{n+1}(x)=x^{-1}\log\left(\frac{f_n(x)}{f_n(0)}\right).\tag2$$
A few initial iterations give us:
$$
\begin{array}{l}
f_1(x)=1+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}+\frac{x^3}{4}+\frac{x^4}{5}+O\left(x^5\right), \\
f_2(x)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{5 x}{24}+\frac{x^2}{8}+\frac{251 x^3}{2880}+\frac{19 x^4}{288}+O\left(x^5\right), \\
f_3(x)=\frac{5}{12}+\frac{47 x}{288}+\frac{2443 x^2}{25920}+\frac{5303 x^3}{82944}+\frac{412589x^4}{8709120}+O\left(x^5\right),
\end{array}\tag3
$$
and their initial terms form the following sequence:
$$1,\,\frac{1}{2},\,\frac{5}{12},\,\frac{47}{120},\,\frac{12917}{33840},\,\frac{329458703}{874222560},\,\dots,\tag4$$
whose denominators grow pretty quickly, but which appear to slowly converge to a value $$\lambda\stackrel{\color{#aaaaaa}?}\approx0.3678\dots\tag5$$

If we assume that the process with the iterative step $(2)$ converges to a fixed point, we can see that it must have a form:
$$f_\omega(x)=-x^{-1}\,W(-c\,x)=c+c^2 x+\frac{3\, c^3\, x^2}{2}+\frac{8\, c^4\, x^3}{3}+\frac{125\, c^5\, x^4}{24}+O\left(x^5\right),\tag6$$
where $W(\cdot)$ is the [Lambert -function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), and $c$ is a coefficient that is not uniquely determined but depends on the choice of the initial function $f_0(x)$. In our case, $c=\lambda$.

---

*Questions:* Does this process actually converge to a fixed point? If yes, then what is a closed-form expression (or another useful description) for $\lambda$?

---

*Update:* An explicit recurrent formula for the coefficients (the parenthesized superscript $m$ in $a_n^{\small(m)}$ is just the second index of the coefficient; the sum $\sum_{\ell=1}^m$ is assumed to be $0$ when $m=0$):
$$f_n(x)=\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_{n\vphantom{+0}}^{\small(m)}x^m,$$
where
$$a_{0\vphantom{+0}}^{\small(m)}=1,\quad a_{n\vphantom{+0}}^{\small(m)}=\frac1{\,a_{n-1}^{\small(0)}\,}\left(a_{n-1}^{\small(m+1)}-\frac1{m+1} \sum_{\ell=1}^m\ell\;a_{n\vphantom{+0}}^{\small(\ell-1)}\,a_{n-1}^{\small(m-\ell+1)}\right).$$
The sequence of coefficients $(4)$ is $\big\{a_{n\vphantom{+0}}^{\small(0)}\big\}$.

Comment: By the mean value theorem, taking $x\to 0,$ you get $$f_{n+1}(0)=\frac{f_n’(0)}{f_n(0)}.$$ Not sure if that helps in any way.

Comment: Whatever the answer could be, this is a nice problem.

Comment: is there a typo in your explicit formula? We are after $a_n^{(0)}$ and when I tried plug $m = 0,$ the sum starts at $l=1$ and ends at $l = m.$

Comment: The formula is correct. We assume that $\sum_{\ell=1}^0(\dots)=0$, because there are no indices satisfying $1\le\ell\le0$, so the sum is empty .

Comment: I think $\lambda =1/e=0.367879441\ldots$. A rough argument is as follows. It seems that each $f_n(x)$ is singular at $x=1$. Since the limit function is $-x^{-1}W(-\lambda x)$ and $W(z)$ is singular at $z=-1/e$, $\lambda$ should be $1/e$ in order for $f_\omega(x)$ to be singular at $x=1$.

Comment: I concur with Claude and will go further saying this is a very nice problem in every respect.

Comment: it says the limit is $1/e$ [here](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C1%2F2%2C5%2F12%2C47%2F120&sort=&language=&go=Search).

Comment: @mathworker21 Thanks! It would be nice to see a rigorous proof. I haven't been able to prove it myself so far.

Comment: @mathworker21 Usually, OEIS keeps numerators and denominators as distinct sequences. This entry mixes them into one interleaved. Probably this is why I was not able to find the coefficients in OEIS after I computed a few of them.

Comment: Originally I found this sequence when I tried to construct the continued exponent expansion of the Fibonacci numbers: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/FHAQfurVQAANsLx?format=png&name=large, but later realized I can get it simply from $1/(1-x)$.

Comment: Another very interesting question is how fast do denominators grow (or would grow if we ignored occasional cancellations of some of their factors with numerators). Empirically, they appear to grow (very roughly) doubly exponentially: $2^{2^{n-0.97942\dots}}$.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov It seems that, if $f_n(0)=a/b$ (in lowest terms), then the denominator of $f_{n+1}(0)$ is a small multiple ($2$ or $6$) of $ab$. Let $b_n$ be the denominator of $f_n(0)$. If $f_n(0)$ converges to a limit $\lambda$, then this would imply that $b_{n+1}$ is multiplicatively not far off from $\lambda b_n^2$, which gives double-exponential growth.